# How to read xlsx or xls files in angular js

Tags: angularjs, xls, xlsx

Is there any way to read content of xls or xlsx file in angular (1.*) Js on client side?

I have tried this solution:

https://code.ciphertrick.com/2016/06/05/read-excel-files-convert-json-node-js/

But the problem is that it was not written for angular Js.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same so I used [**alasql**](http://alasql.org/).

It does have so many other options also. so try using it.